# what does "sudo dpkg --configure -a" do exactly?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I was uninstalling the mGBA emulator from my ubuntu system because it wasn't working properly. I tried uninstalling it via the command line and was met with this error.
`dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`
I ran the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and a bunch of random things started installing.

I'm a complete noob to this stuff. Did I mess up my system or install something I shouldn't have that would break the OS or leave it vulnerable?

Thanks! ^_^

Answer (score 2):

If `apt` is interrupted for some reason, packages that have been downloaded and unpacked may not have been fully configured, or installed.

> From `man dpkg`
>
> ```
>    --configure package...|-a|--pending
>           Configure a package which has been unpacked but  not  yet  configured.
>           If  -a  or  --pending  is  given  instead of package, all unpacked but
>           unconfigured packages are configured.
>
>           To reconfigure a package which has already been  configured,  try  the
>           dpkg-reconfigure(8) command instead.
>
>           Configuring consists of the following steps:
>
>           1.  Unpack  the  conffiles,  and  at  the  same  time  back up the old
>           conffiles, so that they can be restored if something goes wrong.
>
>           2. Run postinst script, if provided by the package.
> ```

The `--configure` option causes dpkg to finish configuration of partially installed packages, and the `-a` indicates that rather than a specific package, all unpacked, but unconfigured packages should be processed.

Comment: Thank you Charles, so by running that command, "sudo dpkg --configure -a", I didn't break my system or make it vulnerable?

Comment: @rickykakashi That command should not break your system, but instead finish installation of programs that had halted for some reason.